# omxplayer wont run on raspbian lite (Pi 2 Model B)

Tags: omxplayer, raspbian-lite

I am trying to build a display for a museum which loops 1 video using an old Pi 2. I am using Raspbian Lite (4.14.79-v7+), because I want to eventually set up the SD card to be read only as I know it will get hard powered by someone at the end of the day.

I have installed omxplayer with `apt-get`. if I run `omxplayer` I get:

```
/usr/bin/omxplayer.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libvorbis.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I can use `apt-cache` to see libvorbis is installed:

```
sudo apt-cache policy libvorbis0a 
libvorbis0a:
  Installed: 1.3.5-4+deb9u2
  Candidate: 1.3.5-4+deb9u2
  Version table:
 *** 1.3.5-4+deb9u2 500
        500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf     Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

`libvorbis.so.0` is in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Mar 16  2018 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libvorbis.so.0 -> libvorbis.so.0.4.8
```

I have tried making a symlink at `/usr/lib/libvorbis.so.0` but this didn't change the error.

I even tried `sudo apt-get purge omxplayer` then `sudo apt autoremove`. Then doing `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`, then installing omxplayer again. Same error.

I am now out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the SHA256 of the download and it was fine. So `DD`ed the `.zip` to the SD card again and it all worked this time. Something must have gone wrong when creating the disk.

Comment: Good solution! +1. You can't upvote your answer, but you *can* select it as the correct answer by ticking the check mark. If you'll do this, two good things will happen: 1) you'll get 15 points, 2) the robot will stop "recycling" your question :)

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.